# How to write CheckAndPut operation in Hbase Shell?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, bigdata, cloudera

I am looking to convert this operation in Hbase shell ?
**table.checkAndMutate(row, family).qualifier(qualifier).ifNotExists().thenPut(put)**

When I write 'checkAndPut' in Hbase Shell , I am facing undefined method ? Anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not supported https://learnhbase.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/hbase-shell-commands. Why do you need it in `hbase shell`?